# Can't type python after sourced venv

Tags: python, linux, python-venv

My project was working using `python3.11`, but was't using `python3.9`. I installed python3.9 and

```
python3.9 -m venv venv3.9
```

in same directory with project. So i had in project folder:

```
.venv
.venv3.9
```

I changed code to work with python3.9, and **deleted** `venv3.9`:

```
rm -r ./venv3.9
```

Then wanted go back to python3.11's venv  with

```
russich555@555russich:/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/21.intercom_record$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) russich555@555russich:/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/21.intercom_record$ python
Command «python» not found...
```

Okay, i can run it directly:

```
venv/bin/python
```

But why is it happening and how to type just `python` inside venv again?

Comment: https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv#Python_venv_activation: `source myvenv/bin/activate`

Comment: @ThomasWeller if you can scroll code block you would see that i tried it